# My disk drive randomly started burning discs with -002 read errors. Is it hardware issue or a software issue?

Tags: disk-drive

My internal disk drive In my emachine pc started burning discs that have -002 unrecoverable read errors. It started happening a few weeks ago. I have tried to burn cds and dvds but both have the same error. The disc drive can read discs perfectly. The disc starts getting read errors at about 1.56% to 7.8%.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Reading and writing in a DVD drive is done using two different lasers. It is not unusual for the write laser to degrade and lose power so that it isn't able to write DVDs properly anymore. How many DVD have you burnt using that drive?

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that the issue is caused by dirt on the laser.

There are CD/DVD lens cleaner disks which can easily be used.